# 'change' event, ajax and live() on IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, live

I read a lot of posts about the problem I have, but haven't been able to fix it. I'm using jquery 1.5.1 and I have a problem with 'change' event on IE7. Since interoperability is a must, I've been trying (unsuccessfully ) to get live() with 'change' event to work on IE7.

Some people have suggested using livequery(), but for me, this is also not a solution.

Is there a way to make options form loaded with ajax respond to 'change' event on IE7 and what would you suggest?

Btw, code works perfectly on IE8 and FF.

Thanks!
Newman

Comment: which element you are using change event with? textbox, select list etc?

Comment: select list, sorry, I wrote "options" which doesn't mean much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you r not rendering select list with ajax u better use $(selector).change in document.ready function live will not propagate change event of select list in IE so you have to attach event handler to the select list itself. 
**Edit** i load select list using following code

```
$.ajax({
type:"post",
url:"/controls/selectlist",
dataType:"html",
success:function(data)
{
    $("#result").append(data);//data will contain html of my select list with ID = mylist
    $("#mylist").change(function(){
       //put event handling code here
    });
}
});
```

Comment: OK, but, if it's loaded with ajax after page load, how can this work? Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: if it is loaded through ajax then u will have to attach event handler in call back function after rendering select list on the page. eidted my answer too

Comment: OK, I'll try this and let you know about the result. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of live?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me , must be your code or browser...

See my example here
http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/82Adg/3/

```
    $("select").live('change', function(){
alert('change')
    });

$("#button").click(function(){
$("body").append("<select><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option></select>")
    return false


});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! And yes, I've tried pretty much everything and as I said it works fine on IE8 and FF but no luck with IE7 :(

Comment: Hm. Maybe the problem is that I load ajax content using load() function?